# Python error - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Tags: python

I am trying to debug an existing script and got the below error when I run the script. `./check_tandbergvideo CE s 10.50.174.138`
This script tries to check if an endpoint is registered or not registered and returns status.

> Traceback (most recent call last):  File "./check_tandbergvideo",
>   line 156, in   main() File "./check_tandbergvideo", line 114,
>   in main  EP = getXML(sys.argv[3],sys.argv[1]) File
>   "./check_tandbergvideo", line 79, in getXML  H323Status =
>   getElement(tree,xml2+"H323/"+xml2+"Gatekeeper/"+xml2+"Status")     +
>   ". Errors: " +
>   getElement(tree,xml2+"H323/"+xml2+"Gatekeeper/"+xml2+"Reason")
>   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Here is the part of code that throws the error.

```
if model == "CE":
  # SIPStatus =  getElement(tree,xml2+"SIP/"+xml2+"Registration/"+xml2+"Status") + ". Errors: " + getElement(tree,xml2+"SIP/"+xml2+"Registration/"+xml2+"Reason")
    SIPStatus =  str(getElement(tree,xml2+"SIP/"+xml2+"Profile/"+xml2+"Registration/"+xml2+"Status")) + ". Errors: " + str(getElement(tree,xml2+"SIP/"+xml2+"Profile/"+xml2+"Registration/"+xml2+"Reason"))
    H323Status = getElement(tree,xml2+"H323/"+xml2+"Gatekeeper/"+xml2+"Status") + ". Errors: " + getElement(tree,xml2+"H323/"+xml2+"Gatekeeper/"+xml2+"Reason")
    ReleaseKey =   getElement(tree,xml2+"SystemUnit/"+xml2+"Software/"+xml2+"ReleaseKey")
    EPModel = getElement(tree,xml2+"SystemUnit/"+xml2+"ProductId")
SWVer =getElement(tree,xml2+"SystemUnit/"+xml2+"Software/"+xml2+"Version")
    else:
    badSyntax()
EPData = {"Model":EPModel,"SIP":SIPStatus,"H323":H323Status,"RK":ReleaseKey,"SW":SWVer}
return(EPData)
```

Could you please verify if the second line of the code H323 has correct syntax?

Comment: One of your `getElement`'s is returning `None`. Do some debugging to find out which one it is.

Comment: Check your getElement() params, one of them is of type 'NoneType' causing the issue.

Comment: And the element in question is `xml2` (it's the only one to which a string is added).

Comment: Yes....indeed, can you post the code relevant to `xml2`

Comment: specifically likely `getElement(tree,xml2+"H323/"+xml2+"Gatekeeper/"+xml2+"Status")` is returning `None`. Fix that and you should be good.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not an error in your script. It just says `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'` that basically means that it can't combine `None` and `"string"`. You should do `str(None)+"string"` or put some condition `if s == None: do something` to avoid.

Comment: I'd recommend very emphatically against the `str()` casting approach, because that will create garbage data, cause errors elsewhere, or create garbage data (or possibly even corrupt existing data) elsewhere.

Comment: That's how it works if you want to add a string to None. Do you know any other method? Let me know.

Comment: Why in the world would you want to add a string to `None`? I think it's pretty obviously an undesired behavior here. You're just appeasing the error message instead of fixing the problem.

Comment: You don't need to do str(None) to do `if s == None: do something`. str(None) != None, two different things that must not be confused or interchanged.

Comment: For the ones who аre unaware. "None" is the absence of a value. It's not an error.  You can record it as "None" or "" or skip it entirely. It's up to you how you will handle it. The error you will get if you try adding None to a string.

Comment: In this case, `None` is probably an indication of an error: wherever the variable `xml2` came from, it's occasionally (or perhaps always) not providing an expected result. If you just call the bug a feature and send "NoneSystemUnit/NoneSoftware/NoneVersion" to the function, you're pretty much guaranteed to get an exception eventually... if you're lucky.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot everyone for your valuable inputs...I tried this and it worked.

`H323Status = str(getElement(tree,xml2+"H323/"+xml2+"Gatekeeper/"+xml2+"Status")) + ". Errors: " + str(getElement(tree,xml2+"H323/"+xml2+"Gatekeeper/"+xml2+"Reason"))`