# Using '\n' to place regex findings on a line for seperation. '+' unsupported operand

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, netscaler

So yesterday I got my regex to be printed line for line. Today I removed my if statement, set "result" equal to the regex so I could append it to my list. Well it broke my (dns+'\n'). Maybe related or not. the error that is being displayed to me is the following.

```
    dns.append(result+'\n')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Code:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

dns = []
addstrip = []
with open('ns.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.read().splitlines()

    for line in lines:
        #result = (re.search(r'(\W\S+)(\.)(\S+)(\.)(\S\S\S+)', line))
        result = (re.search(r'^(add lb vserver) (\S+)(\.)(\S+)(\.)(\S+)', line))
        dns.append(result+'\n')
        print(dns)
    with open('dnsout.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(str(dns))
```

Output with no '\n'

```
[None]
[None, None]
[None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

OLD Code:

```
dns = []
with open('ns.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.read().splitlines()
    for line in lines:
        if re.search(r'^(add lb vserver )(\S+) (\S+) (\S+)(.+)$', line):
            dns.append(line)
            print(dns)
    with open('dnsout.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(lines)
```

Later Output After the 'None':

```
match='add lb vserver SSL_INT_unucrepSL.oncologysupply.c>, <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 51), match='add lb vserver SSL_EXT_unucrepSL.oncologysupply.c>, <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 57), match='add lb vserver SSL_INT_hotfixunucrepsl.oncologysu>, <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 57), match='add lb vserver SSL_EXT_hotfixunucrepsl.oncologysu>, <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 57), match='add lb vserver SSL_EXT_hotfixunucwcfsl.oncologysu>, <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 57), match='add lb vserver SSL_INT_hotfixunucwcfsl.oncologysu>, <_sre.SRE_Match object;
```

In the above code I was not actually printing out the regex findings but rather the whole line. The output was line by line though maybe bc the regex findings are different datatype?

Pandas is being used later on in code below this so you can ignore. How would one go about separating by line? My guess is that I will need to convert it to some other type that can take the +'\n'. Any help, tips, or tricks are appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Did you have 'if result:' before dns.append ?

Comment: I shall edit my post and include it.

Comment: When the regex.search can't find any text that matches your expression (r'...') it returns a None, you have tried to append '\n' to None.

Comment: Would you like a `None` result replaced with an empty string `''`, or will that lead to problems later on?

Comment: Not sure where I would append the '\n' to None. I updated the above with what comes after the None's

Comment: Not at all, the None's are not important so I do not mind the removal of them.

Comment: Read the words of the error message. Clearly your `re.search` is not finding a match, meaning it returns `None`, and you can't append `None` and `str`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454908/split-java-string-by-new-line

Comment: But in that case, if I switch the re.search to re.split, I still cant +'\n' even when the output has no "None"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python error - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30904667/python-error-typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-nonetype-and-str)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comments,

```
import re
import pandas as pd

dns = []
addstrip = []

    with open('ns.txt', 'r') as file:
        lines = file.read().splitlines()

        for line in lines:

            result = (re.search(r'^(add lb vserver) (\S+)(\.)(\S+)(\.)(\S+)', line))
            if result:
               dns.append(result.group(x)+'\n') # x is the group number that you would need. 
               print(dns, end=",")
        with open('dnsout.txt', 'w') as f:
          f.writelines(str(dns))
```

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: '_sre.SRE_Match' and 'str'

Comment: There has to be a way to restructure it or change the datatype in order to add the +'\n'

Comment: I noticed that everything that should be on the next line actually ends in a comma. Maybe after its written, somehow separate them by the comma. hmm