# the exe file made by py2exe occured pystary error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class TestSysTray:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master        
    
    def show_window(self, icon, item):
        self.icon.stop()
        self.master.after(0, self.master.deiconify)        
    
    def quit_window(self, icon, item):
        self.icon.stop()
        self.master.destroy()                 
    
    def withdraw_window(self):  
        self.master.withdraw()
        image = Image.open(r'test.png')
        menu = pystray.Menu(item("Show", self.show_window, default=True), item("Quit", self.quit_window))
        self.icon = pystray.Icon("name", image, "TEST", menu)
    
        self.icon.run()
```

I programmed python GUI program with tkinter and pystray.

And make exe file by using py2exe.

But when I execute the program, the errors occured below.

How could I fix this bug?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>    
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load    
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked    
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked    
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible    
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module    
  File "systray.pyc", line 6, in <module>    
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load    
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked    
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked    
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible    
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module    
  File "pystray\__init__.pyc", line 48, in <module>    
  File "pystray\__init__.pyc", line 40, in backend    
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't share enought informations of your script.

We don't know the libraries you are using except pystray and tkinter.
I think that also you are using `PIL` to import `Image`. It's necessary to share them to understand your program...

There is a similary issue in this post : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30904764/16092732).

You can't concatenate `None` and `string`.

You shall create an initialization or create a condition to avoid this issue.

To create an exe, you can use `pyinstaller` or `auto-py-to-exe` using pyinstaller module but this library is really easy to handle.

If you want to use py2exe module, I created a setup script to your program :

```
from setuptools import setup
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(options = {
    "py2exe":
    {   
        "excludes": ["_pytest","qtpy"], 
    }
},
  console=['blueconcerto.py'])
```

but I don't know if it's fonctionnal with your others programs.